# Melbourne unusual/underground dining

Tags: food-and-drink, melbourne

I'm planning to hit melbourne and have a spare night on the 1st Aug. I've heard/see online sometimes they have one-off or irregular special dining events (36 collective, the gypsy kitchen) that are fantastic to try. Does anyone know of one happening on the 1st Aug or a gastronomy that isn't awkward to go to by yourself?

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about a very specific date and event, and unfortunately won't be useful to anyone else in the future.